# Scaling instance group between 0 and 1 instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, autoscaling

The instance group is set to scale based on a custom metric. Min. number of instances is 0, max number is 1. I need the group to scale to 0 instances if the metric utilizationTarget is less than 4, but it does not.

The number of instances is 1.
I tried to increase the metric value above the utilizationTarget and it seems like it want's to scale to 2 instances, because I see a warning about the reached instances limit.
What am I doing wrong?

```
autoscaler:
  autoscalingPolicy:
    coolDownPeriodSec: 120
    customMetricUtilizations:
    - filter: resource.type = "global" AND resource.labels.project_id = "projectid"
      metric: custom.googleapis.com/stores/main_load
      utilizationTarget: 4.0
      utilizationTargetType: GAUGE
    maxNumReplicas: 1
    minNumReplicas: 0
    mode: ON
```